# How can I modify the Python environment without breaking my system interpreter?

Tags: python

In my work I have installed python, but to work on other project I am supposed to use python interpreter with some tweaks, which is fine, but packages inside are trying to access packages in python, which is in system directory, numpy to be precise.
I changed in powershell the pythonpath to be

```
PYTHONFOLDER="path/to/python/folder"
PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONFOLDER%\Lib;
```

But the results are same. Can I turn existing directory into virtual one? Can I specify where to get packages to python?
Thanks

Comment: What tweaks ? Also you needn't define PYTHONPATH like that - Python by default always looks into it's own lib directories to find what it is trying to install. PYTHONPATH is intended for your personal modules/packages.

It isn't clear what you mean that numpy is installed in the system directory - where exactly ?

Comment: I downloaded python with numpy inside in C:\tweakedPython\site-packages but numpy is opened from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy which because of different versions give [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: So where is Python installed - and how did you 'download python with numpy 'installed - that isn't clear to me.

Comment: Python is normally installing packages to the one path, I downloaded a zipped version of python somebody else installed, where the person already installed all the packages with correct version etc. with some tweaks i was told.

Comment: I would simply use pip to install the packages - rather than download sonething that someone else has built; but that is just me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would recommend using [virtual environments.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) This will allow you to have separate sets of packages (with unique versions) for each project.

Comment: But my question was if I can turn downloaded python with its packages into a virtual enviroment.

Comment: Normally - you create a Virtual environment based on a specific version of Python and once the VE is created you use pip to install the packages directly into that virtual environment. You DON'T need to download python again.

Comment: I know that you don't have to install python again. I have large number of packages and I am asking if I can use them and only them.

Comment: When you create a virtualenv, you get an option as to whether system packages remain available inside it. Look at `virtualenv --help`.

Comment: @AntonínProcházka Please read the documentation on virtual environments. That should answer all of your questions on this.